# Probability that you win in rock scissors paper with 3 players?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Let's say person A, person B and person C are playing rock paper scissors.

Clearly $n(S)=3\times 3\times 3=27$. We want to find the probability that person A wins.

$n(\text{only A wins})=3$ (A wins with rock/scissors/paper).

$n(\text{A and one other person wins})=2\times 3=6$
($2$ ways to choose the other winner, $3$ ways to win (rock/scissors/paper))

$\therefore P(\text{A wins})=\frac{3+2\times3}{27}=\frac{1}{3}$, but this is flawed but this because it doesn't account for the probability where you draw. (i.e. if the probability of each person winning is $\frac{1}{3}$, then the total probability is already $1$, when we haven't accounted for the probability of drawing yet.)

What is the correct probability that you will win in a game of rock scissors paper with 3 players? Thanks.

Comment: You count the case where A and B win, and also the case where B and A win, though they're the same case.  Instead of $12$ cases where two people win, there are only $9$ ($3$ ways to choose the two winners, and $3$ ways to win.)

Comment: Doubt - Lets say the three players put rock, paper and scissors respectively. Would you consider that as a win for all 3 participants, or just a draw?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, you are correct.. But what is the probability that one person wins?

Comment: @SmritiSivakumar That would be a draw. Draw is when all three people put rock/scissor/paper, or there is one of each.

Comment: The probability of A winning really is 1/3 (and 1/3 of losing, 1/3 of drawing). What is incorrect is then summing this winning probability for all three players because these are not mutually exclusive events - more than one player can win at the same time. If you take that overlap into account, there is room for draws.

Comment: What if two players choose "sciccors" and one "paper" ? Do then two players win ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sample space contains $3\times 3\times 3=27$ outcomes, as you say.

There are different situations. If all players pick the same symbol, there is not a player that stands out (3 outcomes). If the three players pick three different symbols, there is also not a player that stands out (6 outcomes).

You call these $3+6=9$ outcomes *draws*.

The remaining situations corresponds to two of the players having the same symbol, and the last player having a different symbol. If the symbol held by the two players **beats** the symbol of the remaining player, you use the terminology that the two players *win together* (9 outcomes). However, if the symbol shared by the two players is **weaker** than the symbol chosen by the last player, then the last player *wins alone* (9 outcomes).

You count the number of outcomes where player A wins alone as 3, corresponding to probability that A wins alone on $\frac{3}{27}=\frac19$.

You also correctly count the number of outcomes where player A wins together with another player as 6, corresponding to probability $\frac{6}{27}=\frac{2}{9}$. But in 3 of these 6 outcomes, player B also wins together with another player, and in the other 3 it is player C which also wins. So this overlaps.

This why you cannot say that the (correct!) probability $\frac13$ that A wins either alone or together with one other player does not leave room for the situation where we have a draw.

If we denote a draw with three different symbols $ABC$, the situation where A and B win together as $AB$, and the situation where A wins alone with $A$, and finally a draw with a single symbol repeated threes times $O$, then we have:
$$
P(ABC) = \frac{6}{27} \\
P(AB)=P(BC)=P(CA)=\frac{3}{27} \\
P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=\frac{3}{27} \\
P(O)=\frac{3}{27}
$$
and these eight events are disjoint and make up the entire sample space, and
$$
\frac{6}{27} + \left(\frac{3}{27}+\frac{3}{27}+\frac{3}{27}\right)
+ \left(\frac{3}{27}+\frac{3}{27}+\frac{3}{27}\right) + \frac{3}{27} = 1.
$$

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing wrong with your calculation; each player wins with probability $1/3$. The point is that these are not disjoint events, so $$P(A\text{ wins})+P(B\text{ wins})+P(C\text{ wins})\neq P(A\text{ or }B\text{ or }C\text{ wins}).$$
In fact, the sum of the probabilities is the **expected number** of players who win. (When there are no multiple winners, so the events are disjoint, this number is always $0$ or $1$ and so its expectation is the probability someone will win, but this is not true in general.)

Here $P(\text{no-one wins})=3\times\frac{1}{27}+\frac{3!}{27}=\frac13$, $P(2\text { people win})=3\times 3\times\frac1{27}=\frac13$, and $P(1\text{ person wins})=\frac13$, so the expectation is exactly $1$, consistent with your answer.